# Custom keyboard shortcut for macros in Outlook 2010?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, macros, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have a suite of macros that I used to have linked to buttons in a custom toolbar in Outlook 2007. Using the & encoding I could assign keyboard shortcuts to those macros (e.g. &1 to make Alt-1 trigger that button).

I can't figure out how to do this in Outlook 2010. Is it possible to assign keyboard shortcuts to macros in this new version?

Ramon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't figure out how to set my own shortcuts, however once you add you macro to the **Quick Access Toolbar,** it is automatically assign the keyboard shortcut alt-  where  starts from 1 going from the leftmost icon to the right.